# Personal name contractions and bad connotations - いず as a contraction of 泉 (いずみ)

Tags: names, contractions, connotation

Are there any negative connotations associated with having いず as a contraction of the name 泉(いずみ)?

I know in English you could have 'Randy' as a contraction of Randall, which would generate quite a few snickers.

Are there any such issues with いず? E.g. Homophones, slang etc

There are also alternative spellings (和泉, 泉水, いずみ and いづみ; from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izumi)) which may impact this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find nothing wrong if someone gave a nickname いず to someone. いず happens to have the same sound as 出ず ("to exit"), 居ず ("absent"), and [伊豆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izu_Province) (province), but that won't be a problem.

I don't think いず is very common as a nickname for いずみ, but there's [at least one real person](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1445737819) whose nickname is いず. I personally hear いずみん a lot (though it's not a contraction).